# Запрос DELETE FROM SQL

Tags: sql

Приветсвую, вылетает ошибака Конфликт инструкции DELETE с ограничением REFERENCE "FK_Дисциплина в семестре_Дисциплины". Суть запроса удалить дисциплины по которым хотя бы один студент получал отметку 2

```
DELETE FROM [Дисциплины]
    FROM [Дисциплины]
    JOIN [Дисциплина в семестре] ON [Дисциплина в семестре].[Код дисциплины] = [Дисциплины].[Код дисциплины]
    JOIN [Зачетная ведомость] ON [Зачетная ведомость].[ID дисциплины в семестре] = [ID дисциплины в семестре]
    WHERE Отметка = N'2'
```

Comment: Придётся сначала удить записи, ссылающиеся на удаляемую.

Comment: либо настроить каскадные обновления/удаления

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, настроил каскад, он теперь чистит дисциплины и зачетная ведомость под ноль)